# How do you map data using excel and mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, excel

I am really stuck on this problem. I am given a data set like this:

https://docs.google.com/a/stolaf.edu/document/d/1_cP60lxHjXebd-KyX91xN49TUeiqY3m8GZjDaXXo5NY/edit

I am having a hard time trying to figure how to map the columns together to produce the final dataset shown in the document.

My initial approach was:

1. Save the source data as CSV
2. upload to mySQL
3. Query the database to find the data needed.
4. Place them in a newly created database that has the right schema.

I am not sure this is the best way to look at it but I am really confused on how I can map columns together from a spreadsheet to a database with the right format. Help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: i would process the csv file: 2 loops one would be for a student the 2nd would add rows in to the db for a particular subject for a particular student

Comment: Just make the table schema in both excel and database same. Then you need to save it as CSV and upload it to MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Make the table schema in both excel file and database table same. Then you need to save the excel file as CSV and then simply import to database table. No need of any further queries.

Next thing that may cause you some problem is that you have table schema will empty fields at the right. In such cases, add those column names in the excel file as first row, export it in CSV, and then while importing CSV to MySQL, skip the first row. That will not cause any error, and your task will be done easily.